# Python-Sphinx issues "WARNING: undecodable source characters, replacing with "?":" when using German umlaut

Tags: python-sphinx

Currently I am writing a documentation in German. Hence, I have to use German umlaut-characters (äöü, etc), but Sphinx tells me it has issues with that and issues warnings: " WARNING: undecodable source characters, replacing with "?":"

Note: I did set *language = 'de'* in the *conf.py*...

Any hints?

Comment: You don’t need to set the language at all: we’re way past “language = codepage” dark ages. Thankfully. Make sure that the text files are encoded in UTF-8, i.e. use a good text editor that lets you set that. And configure Sphinx to expect UTF-8 input, if it doesn’t do it by default (I forget whether it does).

Comment: OK, UTF8 does the trick... thanks